# Google sites: How to create internal links

Tags: hyperlink, google-sites, internals

Is it possible to work with links within a page? For example, linking a section heading to another heading?
Thanks for helping!
Thomas

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the link by clicking the clip next to the heading when published.
Here is a video that shows it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ikmKbiFAB24&t=80s